# find siblings until condition is reached

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Consider this simple example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

data = soup("""
<p>
<strong> Hello </strong><br />
this is a nice text
    </p>
    <p>
this is a second text
    </p>
    <p>
<strong> Hello again </strong><br />
this is the third text
    </p>
    <p>
this is the last text
    </p>
""", 'lxml')
```

I am interested in the following : for each `<p>` find the text of `<p>` and all of the successive `<p>`s until the first `<p>` with a `<strong>` tag is reached.

Unfortunately, the following code does not work because it does not stop at the first `<strong>` tag. It returns instead **all** the next siblings without a `<strong>` tag. Indeed, for the first paragraph, the **first subsequent paragraph** with a `<strong>` tag has the text *"this is the third text"*. Parsing should stop there.

```
mypar = data.find_all('p')


for par in mypar:
    sib = par.find_next_siblings()
    filtered = [e for e in sib if not e.find('strong')]
    print(f'the paragraph is {par}')
    print(f'next paragraphs are :{filtered}')
    print('###')
    print('         ')

   the paragraph is <p>
<strong> Hello </strong><br/>
this is a nice text
    </p>
next paragraphs are :[<p>
this is a second text
    </p>, <p>
this is the last text
    </p>]
###
         
the paragraph is <p>
this is a second text
    </p>
next paragraphs are :[<p>
this is the last text
    </p>]
###
         
the paragraph is <p>
<strong> Hello again </strong><br/>
this is the third text
    </p>
next paragraphs are :[<p>
this is the last text
    </p>]
###
         
the paragraph is <p>
this is the last text
    </p>
next paragraphs are :[]
###
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, the first p with a strong is the very first so there should be nothing returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is what you want:

```py
mypar = data.find_all('p')

for par in [e for e in mypar if e.find('strong')]:

    sib = par.find_next_siblings()
    filtered = []
    for e in sib:
        if not e.find('strong'):
            filtered.append(e)
        else:
            break

    print(f'the paragraph is {par}')
    print(f'next paragraphs are :{filtered}')
    print('###')
    print('         ')
```

First we filter the paragraphs to loop only through the ones with a strong tag, because that is our start point.
From there we can loop over the siblings and append to `filtered` until we find another `strong` tag. There we break the loop and print the info.
Then we start over on the next header.

#### Output

```
the paragraph is <p>
<strong> Hello </strong><br/>
this is a nice text
    </p>
next paragraphs are :[<p>
this is a second text
    </p>]
###
         
the paragraph is <p>
<strong> Hello again </strong><br/>
this is the third text
    </p>
next paragraphs are :[<p>
this is the last text
    </p>]
###
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to group:)

```
from simplified_scrapy import  utils, SimplifiedDoc
from simplified_scrapy.core.listex import List
xml = '''
<p>
<strong> Hello </strong><br />
this is a nice text
    </p>
    <p>
this is a second text
    </p>
    <p>
<strong> Hello again </strong><br />
this is the third text
    </p>
    <p>
this is the last text
    </p>
'''

doc  = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
allP = doc.selects('p')
allStrong = allP.select('strong')

count = len(allP)
lastI = 0
for i in range(count):
    if allStrong[i]:
        print (List(allP[lastI:i]).text)
        lastI = i
print (List(allP[lastI:]).text)
```

Result:

```
[]
['Hello this is a nice text', 'this is a second text']
['Hello again this is the third text', 'this is the last text']
```